# Django Modelforms: how to show a select for a CharField?

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I'm using ModelForms in Django to create my form. This works well. However, there is a field that is a charfield in the database, but for a particular form I want to restrict the options that users can enter to a list of specific items - ideally shown in a `<select>`. What would be the right way to do this? Here is my code:

```
form = ModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=Street.objects.get(pk=1))
```

In my models:

```
class Street(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have tried the following:

```
from django import forms
CHOICES = [('1', 'First'), ('2', 'Second')]
choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CHOICES)
form.fields["street"].widget = choice_field
```

Which gives this error:

```
'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

Comment: You assigned a `Field` instance as a `Widget`. Try to define: 1) custom form, as mentioned in first answer, or 2) try to replace field with `form.fields["street"] = choice_field`. The preferred way is 1, where you can redefine `street` field as class property. EDIT: if you want to narrow database records of `Street` model, try to redefine a field's queryset, i.e. `form.fields["street"].queryset = Street.objects.filter(pk__in=(1, 2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to fix this attribute error you can either pass your choices as a python Tuple or set TypedChoiceField() and give it the attribute coerce reference this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200849/14127147

```
from django import forms
CHOICES = (("1", "First"), ("2", "Second"))
choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CHOICES)
form.fields["street"].widget = choice_field
```

Answer (score 5):

The preferred way to use `ModelForm` is to create own class:

```py
class StreetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Street
        fields = '__all__'
```

This would create a form for editing `Street` attributes like `name`.

If you want to create a form with streets to select, and you should define a new  form - an another `ModelForm` if `Street` is in a relation to the other model (i.e. defined by ForeignKey), or a plain `Form` otherwise.

Assuming the second scenario you should define:

```py
class OtherForm(forms.Form):
    street = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Street.objects.all())
```

To narrow streets you have two choices, depending on the filtering criteria.

For static filtering (where criteria would not change at runtime) you can narrow records by defining a filtered queryset:

```py
class OtherForm(forms.Form):
    street = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Street.objects.filter(name__ilike='a%')
    )
```

For dynamic filtering you may override a field's queryset instance in `__init__` method:

```py
class OtherForm(forms.Form):
    street = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Street.objects.all()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # must be called first
        self.fields["street"].queryset = Street.objects.filter(...)
```

The default widget for `ModelChoiceField` is a `Select` widget.

But if you need to prepare custom choices for street names, you should define a choices list (as in your example) and redefine a `name` field of the `StreetForm`:

```py
STREET_NAME_CHOICES = [
   ('Street name 1', 'Street name 1'), 
   ('Street name 2', 'Street name 2')
]

class StreetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=STREET_NAME_CHOICES
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Street
        fields = '__all__'
```